# PHP mailer not functioning properly

Tags: php, html

The code that I am trying to mail with is causing me problems. I want someone to be able to choose a radio button to determine whom to mail (2 choices). Currently if no radio button is chosen mail is sent to both addresses - this works. If you choose one of the buttons mail does not send to target. Below is the pertinant code.

```
<form action="code/submitemailCopy.php" method="post" name="submitform" id="submitform">
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="toaddress" value="tim" id="tim">Tim/label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="toaddress" value="terry" id="terry">Terry</label>


$mailto = $_POST['toaddress'];
if ($mailto == 'terry')
    $mailto = 'example1@example.com';
elseif ($mailto == 'tim')
    $mailto = 'example2@example.com';
else
    $mailto = 'example1@example.com' . ',';                 
    $mailto .= 'example2@example.com;
```

Comment: what is the value of `$mailto` (use `var_dump`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use code blocks. Your last line is always executed, so you end up with `$mailto` value like `example1@example.comexample2@example.com` or `example2@example.comexample2@example.com`

```
if ($mailto == 'terry') {
    $mailto = 'example1@example.com';
} elseif ($mailto == 'tim')  {
    $mailto = 'example2@example.com';
} else {
    $mailto = 'example1@example.com' . ',';                 
    $mailto .= 'example2@example.com;
}
```

Comment: In other words, PHP is not Python.  Exactly what I was about to say, but you got there first.  +1

Comment: Thank You Worked. It may be obvious but I'm not a coder. Info Assurance Professional by trade.